# How to insert css rule into javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, sorting, animation, filtering

```
animation: scaleUp 0.3s linear 0.4s forwards;

animation: scaleDown 0.3s linear forwards;
```

Hi, I'm trying to animate contents when I filter the contents. 
I'm trying to add these two css rules above into javascript code below when 'hide all elements that don't share our class' and when 'show all elements that do share ourClass' but I really don't know how to open and close tags because I don't know much about Javascript. If you could help me I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#filterOptions li a').click(function() {
    // fetch the class of the clicked item
    var ourClass = $(this).attr('class');

    // reset the active class on all the buttons
    $('#filterOptions li').removeClass('active');
    // update the active state on our clicked button
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');

    if(ourClass == 'all') {
        // show all our items
        $('#ourHolder').children('div.item').show();    
    }
    else {
        // hide all elements that don't share ourClass
        $('#ourHolder').children('div:not(.' + ourClass + ')').hide();

        // show all elements that do share ourClass
        $('#ourHolder').children('div.' + ourClass).show();
    }
    return false;
});
```

});

Comment: use a class with the rules you want to add

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am missing something, I see no reason why the following won't work:

```
$("#ourHolder").css("animation","scaleUp 0.3s linear 0.4s forwards");
```

or

```
$("#ourHolder").css({"animation" : "scaleUp 0.3s linear 0.4s forwards"});
```

It is definitely a better practice however to add that css to a class and toggle the classes instead.

Just as a note, i am not sure what selector you will want, I just chose `#ourHolder` as an example.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the fast reply but unfortunately it doesn't work. However, I'm using this simple filtering method from this website.http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/jquery-filtering I just wonder is there any way I can animate contents by using css only. Thanks.

Comment: @Kim: Could you show us what you tried? A jsFiddle would be great.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ejkim2000/J7TF4/ This is what I tried but the animation doesn't work. I'm trying to use filtering system as simple as I can and also try to animate the contents by using css only. Thanks.